# How can I read multiple different regions from a BAM file in R?

Tags: r, sam

I’m trying to process BAM records (of a coordinate-sorted, indexed BAM file) successively in fixed-size, non-overlapping, sliding genome coordinate windows. Unfortunately I am unable to read records via `scanBam` in different windows (`which` parameter): the first call to `scanBam` succeeds but subsequent calls return zero-length results.

By contrast, if I don’t specify a coordinate window and instead use `yieldSize` when opening the BAM file, I can successfully read records in a loop:

```
library(Rsamtools)
bamfile = system.file('extdata', 'ex1.bam', package = 'Rsamtools')
process = function (reads) message(length(reads$seq))
```

```
bam = open(BamFile(bamfile, yieldSize = 1000L))
param = ScanBamParam(what = 'seq')

repeat {
    reads = scanBam(bam, param = param)[[1L]]
    if (length(reads$seq) == 0L) break
    process(reads)
}
```

… where `process` performs the read processing (unimportant for the example).

Now I’m trying to use the following code to work in genomic coordinate windows instead, and it fails as explained above:

```
windowsize = 1000L

bam = open(BamFile(bamfile))
chr = seqlevels(bam)[1L] # Only do one chromosome for now
chrlengths = seqlengths(bam)

result = lapply(seq(1L, chrlengths[chr] - windowsize, by = windowsize), function (pos) {
    which = setNames(RangesList(IRanges(pos, pos + windowsize)), chr)
    param = ScanBamParam(what = 'seq', which = which)
    reads = scanBam(bam, param = param)[[1L]]
    process(reads)
})
```

Conversely, it works if I close and re-open the BAM file in each iteration (i.e. before each `scanBam` call) — but that’s undesirable: it carries a **substantial** overhead (running on an *empty* BAM file with 16 chromosomes in its header takes several *hours*).

It's only returning data from the first iteration, not any subsequent iterations, unless I close the BAM file between scanBam calls.

Since the `process` function is nontrivial and written in R, I’m stuck with R for now. And there’s no reason why this *shouldn’t* work in R.

Am I overlooking something? Is this a bug in {Rsamtools}? Is it “by design”?

Comment: @gringer I’ve noticed that you’ve added the tag into the question title — why? [On Stack Overflow there’s a broad consensus against redundant mentions of the tag in the question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/1968), and in fact I frequently (several times a day, on average) edit to *remove* such mentions from titles on Stack Overflow (most useless taggings are more egregious, but removing “… in X” is a fair share of the edits I make).

Comment: Following the same logic, why not remove BAM from the title? I don't think that "in R" is redundant here. In this case I considered that there were multiple valid Bioinformatics questions that could begin with "How can I read multiple different regions from a BAM file", even with the "R" tag. In this case it seems like you specifically want an R solution, which is why I added it in.

Comment: Are you working under linux? and do you absolutely have to do it in R?

Comment: @user324810 I mean, this question is three years old. And at any rate, regardless of whether somebody “absolutely” has to do this in R, it *should work* in R. But for posterity: yes, I absolutely had to do this in R since the `process` placeholder in my case was a piece of nontrivial logic developed in R over the span of months (in fact, the final implementation was in C++ anyway, the R code was my research prototype for faster iteration). I ended up processing fixed-sized chunks rather than scanning over genomic coordinate windows.